# SSH to Raspberry Pi with same IP but interchangeable OS?

Tags: security, ssh, raspberry-pi, ssh-keys

I have a Raspberry Pi which I run with two different Operating Systems by booting up with different SD cards. This RPi has a static internal IP address (and the same iface mac address), as both Operating Systems have a public IP whenever they are running, allowing me to  SSH from work.

The problem is that I can only SSH into one Operating System given that my `known_hosts` only recognises one key per host, so I would have to delete each time the `known_hosts` entry whenever the Operating System/SD card changes.

I've created two different RSA keys for each system, and on my local machine under `~.ssh/config` given each `Host` an alias and corresponding `IdentifyFile` key, but I still come across the same issue. I've also created one key for both system and still come across the same issue.

Is there any way/method to SSH into my RPi regardless of the OS without having to delete the key each time from `known_hosts`?

Comment: Why don't you use the same key for both systems?

Comment: Hi mkf, even if I use the same rsa key, I get the following message: `The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
8f:9a:aa:a0:ad:9a:87:44:59:ad:ad:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`...`Add correct host key in /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.`

Comment: @antr So you need to use the same server key on both OS's and then install that keys public key in known_hosts.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be on the [Raspberry Pi StackExchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) as it's about the Raspberry Pi not Programming